# Conditional compilation depending on function argument?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I searched far and wide and information on the net seems to suggest that conditional compilation using the preprocessor works exclusively on environment variables.

Basically, I would like to have an inline function or macro perform different operations based in its input arguments. Example of what I want to achieve:

```
inline void foo(int x) {

    #if (x < 32)

        register0 |= (1 << x);

    #else

        register1 |= (1 << (x - 32));

    #endif

}
```

The main goal here is that the resulting inline code will not contain conditional code for constant inputs.

Basically, I currently program for a microcontroller (lpc213x) and would like to have an inline function or macro to do pin configuration setup. Since pin configurations are split across multiple registers (e.g. 0 and 1 above), I would like to perform some conditional checks to decide which register is supposed to be written to for a given pin constant.

However, the pin configurations are all constant at compile time, so I would like to eliminate the conditional checks from compile code. I know that optimization would likely get rid of unnecessary conditionals anyway, but I'm wondering whether there is a way to achieve this behavior explicitly, because I might need to disable optimization in the future.

Thanks,

FRob

Comment: If you are using C++ you can solve this using templates. Don't tag your question C and C++ unless you really have an issue that concerns both of these languages.

Comment: Enable optimization in your compiler and it will magically do this for you. Or use `constexpr` in C++.

Comment: That should probably be `x < 32`, not `x <= 32` (and the `1` should probably be `1U`).

Comment: Sorry, I tagged it C++ because I thought it concerned the C++ preprocessor as well. Untagged C++ as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an ugly way for C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

volatile unsigned long register0 = 0, register1 = 0;

#define DEF0X(_X_) \
  static inline void SetPin##_X_() { register0 |= 1ul << _X_; }

#define DEF1X(_X_) \
  static inline void SetPin##_X_() { register1 |= 1ul << (_X_ - 32); }

DEF0X(0)  DEF0X(1)  DEF0X(2)  DEF0X(3)  DEF0X(4)
DEF0X(5)  DEF0X(6)  DEF0X(7)  DEF0X(8)  DEF0X(9)
DEF0X(10) DEF0X(11) DEF0X(12) DEF0X(13) DEF0X(14)
DEF0X(15) DEF0X(16) DEF0X(17) DEF0X(18) DEF0X(19)
DEF0X(20) DEF0X(21) DEF0X(22) DEF0X(23) DEF0X(24)
DEF0X(25) DEF0X(26) DEF0X(27) DEF0X(28) DEF0X(29)
DEF0X(30) DEF0X(31) DEF1X(32) DEF1X(33) DEF1X(34)
DEF1X(35) DEF1X(36) DEF1X(37) DEF1X(38) DEF1X(39)
DEF1X(40) DEF1X(41) DEF1X(42) DEF1X(43) DEF1X(44)
DEF1X(45) DEF1X(46) DEF1X(47) DEF1X(48) DEF1X(49)
DEF1X(50) DEF1X(51) DEF1X(52) DEF1X(53) DEF1X(54)
DEF1X(55) DEF1X(56) DEF1X(57) DEF1X(58) DEF1X(59)
DEF1X(60) DEF1X(61) DEF1X(62) DEF1X(63)

#define SET_PIN(_X_) SetPin##_X_()

int main(void)
{
  SET_PIN(0);
  SET_PIN(1);
  SET_PIN(32);
  SET_PIN(63);
  printf("register0=0x%08lX register1=0x%08lX\n",
         register0, register1);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
register0=0x00000003 register1=0x80000001
```

Comment: So it is possible :D While I agree that this is somewhat unsightly, I think the overall functionality using a combined SET_PIN function is great :D Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

With C++, you could use template functions, like this:

```
template <bool B>
void doSetRegister(int x);

template<>
inline void doSetRegister<true>(int x) {
    register0 |= (1 << x);
}

template<>
inline void doSetRegister<false>(int x) {
    register1 |= (1 << (x - 32));
}

template <int X>
inline void setRegister() {
    doSetRegister<X <= 32>(X);
}

int main() {
    setRegister<1>();
    setRegister<33>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And if you are coding in C, only thing you can do is to define two versions of foo().

Answer (score 2):

You can remove conditional code by using [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) trick:

```
void foo(int x) {
  x < 32 && (register0 |= (1 << x));
  x >= 32 && (register1 |= (1 << (x - 32)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#define X 15 // or some else

#if X <= 32
#   define SET_X register0 |= (1 << X)
#else
#   define SET_X register1 |= (1 << (x - 32))
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the C Preprocessor to create a set of defines composed of two unsigned longs and then use these as arguments to your function `foo()`, the code is pretty straightforward.  And if you need to add another register, you can modify the defines.

```
#define PIN_00  0x00000001, 0x00000000
#define PIN_01  0x00000002, 0x00000000
// defines left out here
#define PIN_31  0x80000000, 0x00000000
#define PIN_32  0x00000000, 0x00000001
// defines left out here
#define PIN_63  0x00000000, 0x80000000

inline void foo (unsigned long reg1, unsigned long reg2)
{
    register0 |= reg1;
    register1 |= reg2;
}
```

Then to use this function `foo()` you would specify the appropriate define.  Since bitwise ORing with zero makes no change, the registers will be updated appropriately.

```
foo (PIN_00);
foo (PIN_01);
foo (PIN_32);
foo (PIN_63);
```

If you needed to add a way to remove bits you can make a new function using the same defines as follows:

```
inline void fooRemove (unsigned long reg1, unsigned long reg2)
{
    register0 &= ~reg1;
    register1 &= ~reg2;
}
```